# .Net 6 FunctionApp: No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I have created a .Net 5 Azure Function App project and followed the isolated-process with Program.cs file and it is working fine. Now I wanted to change/upgrade the framework version from dotnet 5.0 to 6.0, so changed the version in project's property page and also changed the version in the csproj file. And changed the attribute also from Function to FunctionName but it says the following error in the cmd while running.

Add it shows the following process window more than 1hour when I run my solution.

[image]

[image]

It's not triggering either my Startup.cs or Program.cs after changed the version, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Do you have a public method with attribute [FunctionName("MyFunction")]?

Comment: Yes, I have public methods but it worked for me before converting into .net 6

Comment: It says only Launching local functions process, (Microsoft Visual Studio), the error is vanished now but this one shows continiously

Comment: You could create a new net6 function app and check what is different compared to your existing function app ? Maybe some nuget packages issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Reproduced the same issue by changing the .NET 5 Isolated version to .Net 6 Version in the `.csproj` file of the Azure Functions .Net 5 Isolated Project**:

[image]

I believe .NET 5 Isolated to .NET 6 is not convertible because When I converted .NET 5 Isolated to .NET 6 Isolated by changing only the below tags in `.csproj` file, it worked successfully.

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

[image]
**And the reason I believe that .NET 5 Isolated to .NET 6 working successfully is of both belongs to Out-of-process as shown in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#supported-versions)**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If upgrading from in-process to .Net Isolated, you may need to delete your bin and obj folder. I think it is probably the obj folder really, but it doesn't hurt to do both. This solution worked for me.